# To show the link to a file instead of actual content

Tags: xquery

I am now writing an XQuery script to work as an scenario in Oxygen XML editor. It basically works by connecting to an XML database, and grab the file that match the user's input：

The major fragment of the script is :

```
for $book in collection("/db/portfolio/product?select=*.xml;recurse=yes")

return

<myFile>{$book[contains(article/@product,$product_code) and   contains(article/title,$title)]}</myFile>
```

The result obtained has always been correct, but it will always shows the actual content of the resulting xml file(if there is one). However, what I want is to show a link with the name of the file on it, when user clicks on it, it will open in the Oxygen XML editor window, and the user can edit the content there.

I am not sure whether this is an XQuery issue or the IDE issue, I would love to hear suggestions here, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try [`fn:document-uri()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xpath-functions-20070123/#func-document-uri):

> ```
> fn:document-uri($arg as node()?) as xs:anyURI?
> ```
>
> Summary: Returns the value of the
>   document-uri property for `$arg` as
>   defined by the `dm:document-uri`
>   accessor function defined in [Section
>   6.1.2 Accessors](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-datamodel/#DocumentNodeAccessors)<sup>*DM*</sup>.

Comment: @Alejandro: thx, it now shows the link, but can I make it clickable? So the user can click and open it in the editor window?

Comment: @Robert: If you are producing an XHTML document that will be sended to a browser, I see no problem unless the URI could not be reached because of permissions or protocol.